# How to make search bar render changes after "search" button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im currently trying to figure out how to solve this problem:

[image]

As you can see, the search bar value is initialized to "TSLA", however, instead of replacing the TSLA data widget with an AAPL data widget, below the TSLA widget it shows a new widget for "A", "AA", "AAP" and finally "AAPL", rendering a new widget as I type each letter of the ticker into the search bar.

Here is the code for the search bar, with the state variable "value" being what I pass to my widgets:

```
class OneStockData extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: 'TSLA',
        clicked: false
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}

toggleBtnHandler = () => {
    return this.setState({
        clicked:!this.state.clicked
    })
}

handleChange (event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value })
}


render() {
    const styles = ['button'];
            let text = 'Search';
    return (
        <div>
            <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    <Card>
                        <CardTitle className="text-uppercase text-muted h6 mb-0">Enter Stock Ticker: </CardTitle>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        <div>
                        <button className="button" onClick={this.toggleBtnHandler}>{text}</button>
                        </div>
                    </Card>
                    <Card>
                        <SSIWidget value = {this.state.value}/>
                    </Card>
                </Row >
```

And here is the code in the SSIWidget:

```
class SSIWidget extends  React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

AddWidget = () => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src ="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js";
    script.async = true;
    script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
        {
            "symbol": this.props.value,
            "width": 1000,
            "locale": "en",
            "colorTheme": "light",
            "isTransparent": false
        }
    )
    document.getElementById("myContainer6").appendChild(script); 
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.AddWidget();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.value !== this.props.value) {
        this.AddWidget();
    }
}

render() {

    return(
        <div id="myContainer6">
            <div className="tradingview-widget-container">
            <div className="tradingview-widget-container__widget">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

There are 2 problems going on:

1. It renders an new "SSIWidget" as each letter of the ticker is typed, and stacks them below each other. This is a big no-no, I want the widget where TSLA data is being shown to be the ONLY SSIWidget, and the data replaced by each new ticker after I click "Search"
2. As I clear the search bar, I would want the widget to show the value of "TSLA" as it was initialized to be.

I have tried different search bars and a few resourced on "onClick", but haven't yet found a solution to my issue. Can someone here point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe a problem in the SSIWidget

Comment: @ThakurKarthik Added SSIWidget Code, it looks like that is the case - it adds a new widget if prevprops is not equal to props, so how to change to the search bar to make it pass "value" upon clicking search, and not as you type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain another state say `searchedValue` and update it upon search button click.

**Refactored code**

```js
class OneStockData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "TSLA",
      searchedValue: "TSLA", //<------- here
      clicked: false,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  toggleBtnHandler = () => {
    return this.setState({
      clicked: !this.state.clicked,
      searchedValue: this.state.value === "" ? "TSLA" : this.state.value,  //<------- here
    });
  };

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const styles = ["button"];
    let text = "Search";
    return (
      <div>
        <Container fluid>
          <Row>
            <Card>
              <CardTitle className="text-uppercase text-muted h6 mb-0">
                Enter Stock Ticker:{" "}
              </CardTitle>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <div>
                <button className="button" onClick={this.toggleBtnHandler}>
                  {text}
                </button>
              </div>
            </Card>
            <Card>
              <SSIWidget value={this.state.searchedValue} /> //<------- here
            </Card>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Follow up qn based on comment.

You are appending the child. Before appending you need to clear children.

```js
AddWidget = () => {

    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src ="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js";
    script.async = true;
    script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
        {
            "symbol": this.props.value,
            "width": 1000,
            "locale": "en",
            "colorTheme": "light",
            "isTransparent": false
        }
    )
    document.getElementById("myContainer6").innerHTML = ''; //<----here
    document.getElementById("myContainer6").appendChild(script); 
}
```

Comment: This is great! It solves part of the issue, it does not display a new widget for every letter anymore, but it still stacks the new widget below the old one upon clicking search. It seems to be an issue in SSIWidget, where it is adding a new widget every time previous props does not equal the current props. I added the code for SSIWidget in my original post, is it possible you know the solution to that as well?